# Terminals - Creating Multiple Identical Folders within Subdirectories and Moving Files

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a bunch of files I'm trying to organize quickly, and I had two questions about how to do that. I really appreciate any help! I tried searching but couldn't find anything on these specific commands for OSX.

First, I have about 100 folders in a directory - I'd like to place an folder in each one of those folders.

For example, I have

```
Cars/Mercedes/<br>
Cars/BMW/<br>
Cars/Audi/<br>
Cars/Jeep/<br>
Cars/Tesla/
```

Is there a way I can create a folder inside each of those named "Pricing" in one command, i.e. ->

```
Cars/Mercedes/Pricing <br>
Cars/BMW/Pricing<br>
Cars/Audi/Pricing<br>
Cars/Jeep/Pricing<br>
Cars/Tesla/Pricing
```

1. My second question is a little tougher to explain. In each of these folders, I'd like move certain files into these newly created folders (above) in the subdirectory.

   Each file has a slightly different filename but contains the same string of letters - for example, in each of the above folders, I might have

   Cars/Mercedes/payment123.html 
   Cars/BMW/payment432.html
   Cars/Audi/payment999.html
   Cars/Jeep/payment283.html

Is there a way to search each subdirectory for a file containing the string "payment" and move that file into a subfolder in that subdirecotry - i.e. into the hypothetical "Pricing" folders we just created above with one command for all the subdirectories in Cars?

Thanks so much~! help with either of these would be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using bash, since it is the default shell in OS X. One way to do this uses a for loop over each directory to create the subdirectory and move the file. Wildcards are used to find all of the directories and the file.

```
for DIR in Cars/*/ ; do
    mkdir "${DIR}Pricing"
    mv "${DIR}payment*.html" "${DIR}Pricing/"
done
```

The first line finds every directory in Cars, and then runs the loop once for each, replacing `${DIR}` with the current directory. The second line creates the subdirectory using the substitution. Note the double quotes, which are necessary only if the path could contain spaces. The third line moves any file in the directory whose name starts with "payment" and ends with ".html" to the subdirectory. If you have multiple files which match this, they will all be moved. The fourth line simply marks the end of the loop.

If you are typing this directly into the command line, you can combine it into a single line:

```
for DIR in Cars/*/ ; do mkdir "${DIR}Pricing"; mv "${DIR}payment*.html" "${DIR}Pricing/"; done
```